# Convolution of array

Tags: c++, opencv, convolution

What is different between these convolution algorithms?

Why `y=0` and `y<1, x = 0; x < 1` and the other `y=1` and `y <-1, x <  - 1`.

```
for(int y = 0; y < grey.rows; y++)
    for(int x = 0; x < grey.cols; x++)
        dst.at<uchar>(y,x) = 0;
```

This is the second convolution:

```
for(int y = 1; y < grey.rows - 1; y++){
    for(int x = 1; x < grey.cols - 1; x++)
```

Comment: In first method you will cover entire image, where as in second you will miss boundary by one pixel.

Answer (score 1):

The first loop isn't properly a "convolution" since the assign operation has a "kernel" of size 1. The second example *seems* to use a kernel of size 3, so it needs 3 pixels to work: prev/curr/next (that's why the `for` loops are "shorter")

Answer (score 1):

In the first two for-loops the code is just initializing the probable result array.

In the second two loops the convolution involves a *[convolution kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28image_processing%29)* that is 3x3, so the code in the loop will reference to elements starting from `dst.at<uchar>(y-1 , x-1)` to `dst.at<uchar>(y+1 , x+1)`.

So the kernel cannot be evaluated on the borders, but just starting for pixels placed from 1 instead of 0 and ending to n-2 instead of n-1.

Comment: is the code for(int y = 0; y < grey.rows; y++)
    for(int x = 0; x < grey.cols; x++) to iterates pixel in the border of array?

Comment: these two nested loops iterate over all the pixels of the image, borders included.